# How to get an HTML table to be exactly 36 pixels from the right window edge

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This doesn't appear to possible either with or without CSS - I want a table that's exactly 36px from both the left and right sides of the browser window. I can easily get the left margin set - but it doesn't appear to be possible to get the right margin to be exact (margin-right css seems to be totally ignored, and exacerbated by margin-left settings).

Neither percentages nor fixed width work well for my scenario.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try posting your HTML and CSS? [An example?](http://jsfiddle.net) The only thing I can think of is your table is exactly 20px too many more pixels from the right because the body has a margin of 10px all around by default, but who really knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.tablecontainer {
  padding: 36px;
}
.tablecontainer table {
  width: 100%;
}

<div class="tablecontainer">
  <table>....</table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/3UBK3/

Comment: Ok, if I use padding rather than margin in the css, it appears to *mostly* work. When you narrow the window enough that other elements cause it to scroll, it appears to break down. But that's an acceptable tradeoff. I can't officially answer because it hadn't been 7 hours yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is with position absolute (GolezTrol beat me to it :P)

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xug6K/)

```
div.wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    left:136px;
    right:136px;
}


table
{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Disadvantage is that this takes the div out of the document flow. It can be convenient, but it is probably undesired in this case.

Comment: @GolezTrol True, but considering the OP wanted the table x pixels from the screen edges, I (albeit probably incorrectly) assumed the table would be out of flow.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this by using the width function in jquery on the window and then explicitly set the table width in javascript/jquery.  This would allow you to behave differently depending on the window size if needed.

```
$("#table").width($(window).width()-(2*36));
```

Comment: You can change behaviour by adding classes or loading different style sheet. You create a strong dependance to Javascript and JQuery which is not needed. I'd advise against this solution, unless you are creating a very dynamic page layout.